# Transactional Replication Over Domain

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I am trying to setup transactional replication in SQL Server 2008 R2 on two servers on separate domains. I am able to create the distributor, create the publication, and create the subscription, however when I attempt to initialize the subscription, I receive and error stating "The process could not connect to the Subscriber".

---

**Publisher/Distributor**

Publication - Uses Windows account on Server1 for both Snapshot Agent and LogReader Agent

**Subscriber**

Subscription Process Account: uses Windows account on Server1 to run. This same Windows account is setup on Server2, with db_owner privileges on the database to receive the replicated data.

Subscriber Connection: Impersonate agent process account(Windows Authentication)

---

I have tried numerous combinations of Windows Accounts, SQL Server Accounts, Default SQL Server Agents, Admin accounts, and nothing works. Both servers can ping each other and all the ports are setup correctly as far as I know.

Any help or insight on where to look would be much appreciated.

Comment: The account that the Distribution Agent runs under needs to be a member of the db_owner fixed database role in the subscription database. Can you confirm whether or not this is the case? Is that the agent you were talking about in your question? Hard to tell without clarification. Also, see if anything is logged in the subscriber's error log.

Comment: Also take a look at this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321822

Comment: Are there any trusts set up between the two domains? If they are completely separate (no trusts), then you must use either pass-through authentication or a SQL Server principal to connect across the domain boundary.

Comment: I had everything setup correctly, but double checking the aliases, the IP address was incorrect on one of them. Thank you for your suggestions and for forcing me to double check my work. It is much appreciated.